# Creating FTP Client in Java with java.net -Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, ftp, network-programming, client

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class FTPClient {
protected Socket sk;
protected BufferedReader in;
protected BufferedWriter out;

public static void main (String [] args){
    FTPClient fc1 = new FTPClient("sitename.org",21);
    fc1.Login("user", "password!");
}

FTPClient(String server, int port){
    try{
        this.sk = new Socket(server,port);
        this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sk.getInputStream()));
        this.out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sk.getOutputStream()));

        String response = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

public boolean Login(String user, String pass){
    boolean success = false;
    try{
        sendOut("USER " + user);
        sendOut("PASS " + pass);
        success = true;
        System.out.println("Waiting for response");
        String response = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(response);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Login Failure");
        success = false;
    }

    return(success);
}

public void sendOut(String command) throws Exception{
    if (sk == null){
        throw new Exception("Client is not connected!");
    }

    try{
        out.write(command + "\r\n");
        out.flush();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Hello, I wrote this code as a client to try to connect and login to a server with an FTP connection. However, I keep getting this error message, 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Can someone please help me?

Comment: ftp is port 21 ssh is 22

Comment: I see I'll give it a second try.

Comment: Now it tells me that "Connection refused: connect"

Comment: can you connect with another ftp client e.g ftp on command line..?

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect with filezilla to my server.

Comment: With the same code against proftpd running local i get java FTPClient
220 ProFTPD 1.3.5a Server (ProFTPD Default Installation) [::ffff:127.0.0.1]
Waiting for response 331 Password required for username

Comment: So, the code is correct? Sigh, what could possibly be wrong. Maybe because I am programming in eclipse? I don't quite have a clue anymore.

Comment: I think there must be something wrong with the servers I am testing with.

Comment: Oh, Alright so the servers I am connecting to are not even listen on port 21. When I tested it earlier on filezilla, I was connecting with SFTP on port 22. Sorry for the silly mistake.

Comment: Ok... My School's server doesn't have FTP set up and opened on port 21. So, I started FTP on my server on port 21 and it properly connect now. Thanks for helping me trouble shoot guys *_*

Answer (score 1):

You try to connect to a SSH server, hence you get the unexpected reply. The defualt FTP port is 21.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... My School's server doesn't have FTP set up and opened on port 21. So, I started FTP on my server on port 21 and it properly connect now. Thanks for helping me trouble shoot guys.

Lessons learned: FTP is normally on port 21. However, if there are connection problems, one should check if the server is even listening on port 21 by logging on and using the "sudo netstat netstat -lntu" command. If FTP is not even on, one can install it by running "sudo apt-get install vsftpd".

Thanks everyone for helping me troubleshoot to the answer.